# Reference external xaml styles from library to WPF Main app

Tags: wpf, resources

I have one Main App.exe WPF on VB.NET. Application have one library C#.NET.
App reference project library.

I try to get style from external library but give error.

This is my "Sharp.LIB" project: "Dictionaries/Buttons.xaml"

```
  <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">    
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">        
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hello from style" />        
</Style>
```

This is my second file "General.xaml" to marge all styles. At now I merge only one Buttons styles.

```
  <ResourceDictionary
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Buttons.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Here is my usercontrol from Main vb.net app.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyWF.UC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:ms="clr-namespace:MyStyles;assembly=MyStyles" mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyStyles;component/General.xaml" />       
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" />
</Grid>
```

---

This is my second try. Again failed with the same error according missing file.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyWF.UC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:ms="clr-namespace:MyStyles;assembly=MyStyles" mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
<UserControl.Resources>        
    <ResourceDictionary 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyStyles;component/General.xaml" />      
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" />
</Grid>
```

Error:
Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line number '27' and line position '18'.

{"Cannot locate resource 'general.xaml'."}

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Have you tried a fully qualified pack URI? Look at the 'Resource File Pack URIs' section on the following web page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is unsolved till now: The pack URI should look like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/$assemblyName$;component/$folder$/Style.xaml"/>
```

see [Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/aa970069(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#resource-file-pack-uris):

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in a subfolder of the referenced assembly's project folder.
>
> pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml

e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPF.Controls;component/Templates/Style.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```